# Eigen::ArrayXd versus std::array<double>

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

I need simple containers of double. Should I use the Eigen library with `Eigen::ArrayXd` or the standard library `std::array<double>`. Which one is better ?

Comment: What will you be doing with these containers?  Will you know the size at run time?  Do they need to be of a fixed size?

Comment: If you're looking for a two-dimensional array optimized for numerical methods, use Eigen::Array. Otherwise, use std::array, or std::vector.

Comment: Just need to pass them by reference. I know the size at run time and they will be of a fixed size.

Comment: Just wait: you know at runtime *and* fixed? If that means you might initialise with arbitrary size, but then don't change any more, then `std::array` is out, you need to know size already at *compile* time. Then `std::vector` might yet be an option.

Comment: There are no `std::array<double>`, there is `std::array<double,Some_size_t_value>`

Comment: Generally: prefer standard libraries over third party libraries (eigen in given case) unless you have good reasons for using the latter. Such reasons might be you *are* using the 3rd party API (so you'd have to copy from standard containers to 3rd party ones anyway) or the 3rd party containers being better optimised for the specific task in question.

Comment: The real question is what @NathanOliver asked. Are you going to be doing mathematics on your array that will need the entire eigen library to be downloaded? Or are you just using it to hold an array of doubles? Don’t use third party libraries unless you absolutely need to use their functions.

Comment: yes it is to hold an array of doubles, that's all :)